# Display component name on two lines in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

I would like the [name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68069524/display-description-of-a-component-in-dymola) of a custom component in Dymola to be displayed on two lines.

When I use `%name` or `%paramName` (where `paramName` is the name of a String parameter of the component) in the TextBox, the name gets written on one line, even when there is space for two, and even when i try to use any of the following: `\n`, `<br>`, `\\n`...

So the only solution I found so far was to create two parameters, `nameLine1` and `nameLine2`, and to use them inside the TextBox, where I can put each parameter on a different line easily by using `S`+`RET`.

Yet I find this solution quite cumbersome. Is there any way to do it more easily?

[image: Dymola component with a name on two lines]

Answer (score 2):

No, I think not. That's a very general problem Dymola/Modelica has with text boxes in the graphical layer. There is no auto-wrap.

You have two options (unless you go for your multi-parameter-solution). Make sure that there is not font size set (which is the default), then:

- Use text box with non-zero width. Dymola will try truncate the text (but it's not very good at it)
- Use a text box with zero width. Dymola will automatically adjust the width to the content.

Oh, there is a third, maybe not so bad option: Don't use so long names.